# Queue Channel backed by MQ Queue

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am planning to use a buffered queue channel backed by IBM MQ Queue. I would like the Spring message to be put into a MQ Queue so that each can be handled in a separate transaction and if the  downstream webservice fails it can be re-tried and ultimately put in a backout queue. This way the messages will never be lost.

I see there are implementations for JDBC Message Store and others but I cannot find anything for MQ Queue. Can you please point me if I am missing

```
   <si:service-activator id="eventHandler"
     input-channel="channel1l" output-channel="amountDataChannel"
        method="processEvent" ref="eventService" >
   </si:service-activator>

    <si:channel id="amountDataChannel">
       <si:queue message-store="queueMessageStore ???"/>
    </si:channel>

    <si:chain id="dataChain1" input-channel="amountDataChannel" output-                      
               channel="outputChannel">
        <si:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />

        <si:transformer ref="transformer" method="transformEvent"/>

         ..Make webservice call
   </si:chain>
```

**Update**

After reading through the documentation here is what I am doing though I have a question on transaction manger Should I be giving the transaction-manager which I declared or will it automatically participate using acknowldege attribute. If yes then what is the difference in both of them?

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="amountQueue" jndi-name="jms/amountQueue"   />

<si-jms:channel id="amountDataChannel" queue="amountQueue" connection-
      factory="queueConnectionFactory" transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Also for production ready is there any other attribute which needs to be given ?

Appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [JMS section of the documentation for JMS-backed Channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-channel).

Comment: Thanks..Let me explore this